# Thinking about naming of utility classes in java

Tags: c#, java, naming

I am looking for naming guidlines for non functional (utility) extensions of the common classes.

In C# I used to use some of this:

1) ListExtensions, too long but with extension methods ListExtensions never appears. Usage is just. 
var productList = new List();
productList.MyExtendedMehod();

2) ListHelpers. This was in old C# 2.0 era, usage is ListHelpers.MyExtendedMethod(productList );

Now I am diving with java. What I have learned is Collections, Arrays classes. So how do you name your helper classes. CollectionUtils? Collections? CollectionsEx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think XXXUtils is the common way. Then you can use static imports to get rid of the class name.

```
class FooUtils {
  public static foo(int x) { ... }
}

static import FooUtils.foo;
foo(5);
```

Comment: Yep, my internal c# guy do not like this, but java guy became more and more strong :). So I will stick with this naming. Thanks.

Comment: I'm generally not a fan of static imports. It tends to make code less readable since, if overused, it can become non-obvious where a function is actually defined just by looking at the code.

Comment: @cletus: I agree. Checkstyle does have a check for that ( http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#AvoidStaticImport ), but I still use it for "Utils" classes with static constants.

Comment: @cletus, that's true, but fortunately most Java developers use IDE's. And it's more important how the code reads. Often the Class name really doesn't give anything, only clutters the code.

@VonC: I consider using Checkstyle bad style. It's more irritating than useful, since there are exceptions to the rules. And also, people have a habit of blindly believing what Checkstyle says. With combination of automatic formatter, one can spoil the whole codebase in one night.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) library for some naming ideas. Maybe this library does a lot of things you want to do anyway!

Answer (score 2):

In Java there's a pattern of using plurals like [`java.util.Collections`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) to hold global function-like static methods for the corresponding class/package.

For example,

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

shuffles the list.

Comment: Yep, but problem where to add my methods for collections. CollectionsEx?

Comment: Are there any other examples beyond Collections and Arrays? Most of the libraries (Apache commons, spring, some places in the JDK) use the xxxUtils naming scheme

Comment: XXXCollections where XXX is the name of the product/company.

Comment: I think the word "tradition" is misleading. I am correcting it to "pattern."

Comment: @David, java.util.concurrent.Executors keeps factory methods in there, but it's not very popular.

Answer (score 2):

I always try and use the package name in plural form. Its shorter than Util or Utils and it sounds more english like.

I believe Arrays and Collections from the JDK sound so much better than if they were named ArrayUtils or CollectionUtils.

For a train package my utils would be placed inside a class called Trains.

Comment: I will try both, xxxUtils are more guidline friendly, but plural form is more netural... Feel like a buridan's ass...

Answer (score 1):

1) I haven't seen it a lot, but I believe the good naming scheme is to give a functional name (SynchronizedSet, etc.). You can get examples from [Apache's commons-collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) or [google collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/).

2) The "standard" suffix is Utils - SwingUtils, StringUtils, etc.

Comment: SynchronizedSet is acceptable for instantiable classes, but not for static utility like... Anyway thanks, seems to me I will end with xxxUtils.

Comment: @Mike, I was answering to your case #1, like your ListExtensions

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) has set quite a standard by using XXXUtils pattern.

Comment: Thanks, will look precisely, such libraries are good sources to learn practices.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I try to choose utility class names such that the clase name is part of the method name. For example

```
list = As.list(array);
set = As.set(list);
b = All.notNull(foo, bar, qux, ...);
name = Defaults.to(input, "Joe Random");
value = For.example(StackTest.class, "withSomeValues"); 
b = Is.empty(iterable);
Out.put("Hello, Worlds!");
```

et cetera...